Is there any bound on the size of ring dimension for Torus FHE?
I see that all implementations of TFHE in opensource supports 2^10 to 2^12 size of ring dimensions. Is there any specific reason (crypto) behind choosing the value or can we choose higher dimensions (ofcourse powers of two).
